# Selenium webdriver testng, how to select this xpath/id

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to find the correct Xpath in order to select the link of the HTML code below. I tried with id and also trying to catch the text with xpath but it doesn't work, I would appreciate some help.

```
<td>
  <a id="2018" onclick="goToOperator(50210, 129216, 195481);">
  <img src="/NexxarUtilWeb/images/logo/SWFS_lcc_small.jpg" alt="Logo">
      <br>
       2018 - LCC TRANS-SENDING LIMITED
      </br>
   </a>
</td>
```

Thank u in advance!

Comment: What xpaths have you tried? Does the id remain same on all page loads?

Comment: What data in the HTML is consistent and what is dynamic?

Answer (score 2):

The correct locator would be:

```
WebElement myLink = driver.findElement(By.id("2018"));
```

If you really want to use an XPath you could use:

```
WebElement myLink = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='2018']"));
```

Where the XPath is:

```
//a[@id='2018']
```

I suspect your real problem is that the element does not exist on the page when it is initially loaded but appears after a set amount of time, if that is your problem you want to use an explicit wait like this:

```
WebDriverWait waiting = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10, 100);
waiting.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("2018"));
```

Of course you may not care about it being visible, you may just want it to be present:

```
WebDriverWait waiting = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10, 100);
waiting.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("2018"));
```

If none of this is helpful we are going to need some more detailed information from you about your problem, a stack trace showing the error you are getting would be useful as well.

Comment: I am of course assuming Java since the question is tagged with TestNG.

Comment: Isn't the id locator strategy not supported by all browsers?

Comment: The ID locator strategy uses the JavaScript getElementById method (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).  This is supported by every browser.

Answer (score -1):

In the above case we cant find the element by id(id is dynamically changing)
so, you can use tag name

```
options=driver.find_element_by_tag_name("br")
for option in options:
    if("2018 - LCC TRANS-SENDING LIMITED" in option.text)
        option.click()
```

Comment: How do you know the ID is dynamically changing?  The OP hasn't said that.  The solution you have suggested above cannot work because a <br> element does not have any text (the HTML the OP has supplied is invalid).  Even if it was valid this would be insane as you have no idea how many <br> elements are on the page and you don't know what the OP is trying to do, they may want to validate that the correct text is applied to an element.  If you really want to do what you are suggesting it would be far simpler to do a `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[.='2018 - LCC TRANS-SENDING LIMITED']"));`